# Can Geode flush data to database

Tags: geode

In Geode's Homepage, It says'Super fast write-ahead-logging (WAL) persistence with a shared-nothing architecture that is optimized for fast parallel recovery of nodes or an entire cluster'

Does this mean Geode can flush data to database. If so, what's its mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Geode's [AsyncEventListener](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/developing/events/implementing_write_behind_event_handler.html) to flush data to the database.